# Html table alignment issue in outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I am facing alignment issue in outlook. I am sending following HTML code in mail.

```
<strong>Test Summury</strong><br> 
<table border=0> 
<tr style='width:100%;display:block'> 
<td valign="middle" style='white-space:nowrap;width:100%;display:block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:100%;color:#494961;padding:0px 2px;line-height:23px;letter-spacing:0.027em;word-spacing:0;width:100%'> 
<img src='https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/8S3emk_N9__9dGjV9Sj9qnYVQWLj6dp4ukTDwGoDq3esYAjOleQ_g8PNqrI8-a_FCVltErovcE0AhZwr6L-I_lutmAu8RgE3oi38y-8=s0-d-e1-ft#https://s3.amazonaws.com/bzimages/mandrill/Duration.png' style='display:inline;margin:5px 0 0 0'> 
<p style='display:inline-block;width:15%;margin-left:5px'><b>2 min</b><br>Duration</p> 
<img src='https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/J9_xwl9q8wAIQw7DMq1CkOAKmMhDK9padlPL1jlpzwruQ9lquwQs-sl9g0gfSUdSo0UHny5IQC0VaqxliEL3QZHgdaT1mt4mkAA=s0-d-e1-ft#https://s3.amazonaws.com/bzimages/mandrill/users.png' style='display:inline;margin:10px 0 0 0'> 
<p style='width:13%;margin-left:11px;display:inline-block'><b>12 vu</b><br>Max Users</p> 
<img src='https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/G05_y_qOOgjUTuvc3Jnllh_DnglVGpp86Sp9BhTi0cCV7-BJUjht8APtujeMwTL-pMEh7WQkH_PyY1L5UyTtxaFWyWasJiUfBQ=s0-d-e1-ft#https://s3.amazonaws.com/bzimages/mandrill/Hits.png' style='display:inline;margin:10px 0 5px 20px'> 
<p style='width:20%;margin-left:11px;display:inline-block'><b>13 Hits/s</b><br>Avg Throughput</p> 
<img src='https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/uzImvaoO6Qkxx3A9uC7cV6rZ6qndIo6LRux-l2MylOkfvLU1VflPp_wNdQFdhjDTsZb2cGCfOSe9pXaMbasIq2nS6lS9BrM_3f7b=s0-d-e1-ft#https://s3.amazonaws.com/bzimages/mandrill/Errors.png' style='display:inline;margin:5px 0 5px 20px'> 
<p style='width:11%;display:inline-block;margin-left:11px'><b>100%</b><br>Error</p> 
</td></tr></table>
```

In gmail, it is aligned as I needed,

[image]

however in outlook email it gets distorted.

[image]

Comment: outlook don't accept some CSS, that's why it's not working. for reference whic property don't work check here  https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: its is working find in snippet .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other guy said you code needs a lot of work. Below is what i did with your code. I placed your images and paragraph tags into a table sitting side a div. You will notice outlook conditional statements, these will be ready by outlook only.

This method of coding is called ghost columns and is part of hybrid coding.

```html
<table width="100%" border=0 cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr> 
<td align="center" valign="middle"> 
<div style="width:24%; vertical-align:top; display:inline-block;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><img src='https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/8S3emk_N9__9dGjV9Sj9qnYVQWLj6dp4ukTDwGoDq3esYAjOleQ_g8PNqrI8-a_FCVltErovcE0AhZwr6L-I_lutmAu8RgE3oi38y-8=s0-d-e1-ft#https://s3.amazonaws.com/bzimages/mandrill/Duration.png' style='display:inline;margin:5px 0 0 0'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style='font-family:sans-serif;font-size:100%;color:#494961;padding:0px 2px;line-height:23px;letter-spacing:0.027em;word-spacing:0;'><b>2 min</b><br>Duration</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>


</div>
 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  </td>
    <td width="25%">
  <![endif]--> 
  <div style="width:24%; vertical-align:top; display:inline-block;">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><img src='https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/J9_xwl9q8wAIQw7DMq1CkOAKmMhDK9padlPL1jlpzwruQ9lquwQs-sl9g0gfSUdSo0UHny5IQC0VaqxliEL3QZHgdaT1mt4mkAA=s0-d-e1-ft#https://s3.amazonaws.com/bzimages/mandrill/users.png' style='display:inline;margin:10px 0 0 0'> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style='font-family:sans-serif;font-size:100%;color:#494961;padding:0px 2px;line-height:23px;letter-spacing:0.027em;word-spacing:0;'><b>12 vu</b><br>Max Users</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>


 </div>
 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  </td>
    <td width="25%">
  <![endif]--> 
<div style="width:24%; vertical-align:top; display:inline-block;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><img src='https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/G05_y_qOOgjUTuvc3Jnllh_DnglVGpp86Sp9BhTi0cCV7-BJUjht8APtujeMwTL-pMEh7WQkH_PyY1L5UyTtxaFWyWasJiUfBQ=s0-d-e1-ft#https://s3.amazonaws.com/bzimages/mandrill/Hits.png' style='display:inline;margin:10px 0 5px 20px'> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style='font-family:sans-serif;font-size:100%;color:#494961;padding:0px 2px;line-height:23px;letter-spacing:0.027em;word-spacing:0;'><b>13 Hits/s</b><br>Avg Throughput</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div> 
 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  </td>
    <td width="25%">
  <![endif]--> 
<div style="width:24%; vertical-align:top; display:inline-block;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><img src='https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/uzImvaoO6Qkxx3A9uC7cV6rZ6qndIo6LRux-l2MylOkfvLU1VflPp_wNdQFdhjDTsZb2cGCfOSe9pXaMbasIq2nS6lS9BrM_3f7b=s0-d-e1-ft#https://s3.amazonaws.com/bzimages/mandrill/Errors.png' style='display:inline;margin:5px 0 5px 20px'> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style='font-family:sans-serif;font-size:100%;color:#494961;padding:0px 2px;line-height:23px;letter-spacing:0.027em;word-spacing:0;'><b>100%</b><br>Error</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>

 
</div>
</td></tr></table>
```

Let me know if this is the answer you were after.

Comment: Not exactly what i needed. But it worked after some changes. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe next time you can put in the exact requirement so someone can help you better?

Comment: Requirement was exact. When I send mail using ur code, it was still distorted hence need to do changes in width of tables. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0bUOGPwAXuPOTgwRzZuSERGMTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I see where it went wrong. It was the TD with 100% width. It's an easy fix. I updated my answer to reflect that as well. A one up would be nice ;-)